Are function calls guaranteed to be strict in C?
In general in the C programming language operators have no guaranteed evaluation order, motivated by the fact that this frees up the compiler to perform optimizations related especially to pipelining.
However, there are some operators such as ? :, &&, and * (for IEEE floats) that must have well-defined evaluation orders.
Is the function call operator () guaranteed to be strict?
It appears that () is indeed guaranteed to be strict given that clang -O3 loops forever given the following code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int bottom(void) {
    while (1) {}

    return 0;
}

__attribute__((always_inline)) int ifte(bool cond, int expr1, int expr2) { return cond ? expr1 : expr2; }

int main(void) {
    (void) printf("%d\n", ifte(true, 0, bottom()));

    return 0;
}

but prints 0 and successfully terminates given
int main(void {
    (void) printf("%d\n", true ? 0 : bottom());

    return 0;
}

In fact, for the first case clang does optimize the code, but in a way that preserves the semantics of strict evaluation:
main:
.LBB2_1:
    jmp .LBB2_1


If you're asking if all parameters are evaluated before the call, then yes. always_inline has no effect on this and on anything else other than performance.
